# HttpContext.Current.Items is working on local but not on prod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httpcontext

I have a C# ASP.net Web Forms 4.5 website.

My problem is that HttpContext.Current.Items is working on my local machine but not on prod. With that I mean that when I insert an item into Items, I can get it again there but when I try to get it in a later lifecycle event on a sub usercontrol, it is not there.

Any clue about how it can be different on local and prod?

Any IIS settings I might be missing?

Insert:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Model", Model);
```

Get:

```
Model = (ProgramComponentViewModel)HttpContext.Current.Items["Model"];
```

Comment: Do you use async request processing somewhere?

Comment: In this case it is not async

Comment: Hmm can't think of anything else. Is it possible that you have some async processing on a non-obvious place like a base page or something.

Comment: No not in that part, but I have multiple calls to DataBind. But I just can't think of a case that should could cause the Items to change.

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same issue except with HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.